# ConnectionStrings error c#

Tags: c#

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeathWish"].ToString();
                con.Open();
                string query = string.Format("Select [ID],Decision from Data where [ID]='{0}' order by Decision", textBox1.Text);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string[] s = new string[] { };
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    s = dr["Decision"].ToString().Split(',');
                }
                int length = s.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string fetr = s[i];
                    for (int j = 0; j <= checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (checkedListBox1.Items[j].ToString() == s[i])
                        {
                            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(j, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

`string query = string.Format("Select [ID],Decision from Data where [ID]='{0}' order by Decision", textBox1.Text);` is the line with error.
2nd picture edited* I wanted to retrieve a specific value on the database using checkedboxlist

this is the image:

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4zjX.png)
[i wanted to retrieve the data on the database and show the specific value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qefQz.png)

Comment: Well, has `con` already been opened prior to you trying to set the connection string? The fact it's a field instead of a method variable would indicate other methods have access to it so check if you've forgotten to close it some place (hell, you're not even closing it in your `button2_Click` method).

Comment: Or just check if the connection is open before changing the connectionsttring or opening it again.

Comment: Also you should read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx this will help you to prevent Sql Injections.

Comment: _"string query = string.Format...is the line with error"_ - actually I suspect it is the line **two lines before it**

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things:

Consider enclosing your DB access code in a `using` block, and instantiating a new connection using your connection string. This ensures that - either by error or by completion of the block - the connection is correctly closed and disposed off.

Secondly, moving the try/catch inside of the using statement is good practice if you're also working with transactions, as you can commit on completion or rollback in your `catch` block.

Finally, **never** use string concatenation to build your queries, when the source of the data you're concatenating with comes from a user control (hell, just never do it). SQL injection is still the OWASP number 3 security risk in software to this day, and it needs to be squashed.

Mandatory reading:

[OWASP - Top 10 Web Application Security Risks](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/)
[SQL Injection - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
[SQL Injection - Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        // a SqlConnection enclosed in a `using` statement will auto-close, and will ensure other resources are correctly disposed
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeathWish"].ToString())) 
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open()
                string[] s = new string[] { };                    
                string query = "Select [ID],Decision from Data where [ID]=@id order by Decision";
               
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter();
                idParam.ParameterName = "@id";
                idParam.Value = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    s = dr["Decision"].ToString().Split(',');
                }
                int length = s.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string fetr = s[i];
                    for (int j = 0; j <= checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (checkedListBox1.Items[j].ToString() == s[i])
                        {
                            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(j, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Only thing is if using `TransactionScope` [there is no rollback and so no need for the `try-catch` to be inside the `using`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943892/585968) unless of course you are referring to _`SqlTransaction`_

Comment: Agreed, I've just always done this to build muscle memory. Basically "You're dealing with the database, just adopt this so it doesn't catch you out if you forget" but I do agree that in this case it's not relevant.

Answer (score -2):

Your Connection is (still) open, so you have to check if it is closed. If it is you can open a new connection.

So try this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                 con.Open();
            }
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeathWish"].ToString();


            string query = string.Format("Select [ID],Decision from Data where [ID]='{0}' order by Decision", textBox1.Text);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string[] s = new string[] { };
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                s = dr["Decision"].ToString().Split(',');
            }
            int length = s.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                string fetr = s[i];
                for (int j = 0; j <= checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (checkedListBox1.Items[j].ToString() == s[i])
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(j, true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure that will still barf on `con.ConnectionString = ...`

Comment: You need to put the `if` block before the connectionString is changed.